# Pure HTML/CSS image autosizing in table with a dynamic text content

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a pure HTML/CSS (no script) solution for a table with two images that needs to be autosized based on the text content in other cells.

Desired 4x2 table configuration is as [follows](https://jsfiddle.net/bd0c2sgj/):

[image]

First columns contains images that should keep their original width:height ratios. First row [image](http://worldartsme.com/images/nba-logos-clipart-1.jpg) should be autosized having 100% height of the 3rd column. Second row [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e4/NHL_Logo_former.svg/996px-NHL_Logo_former.svg.png) should be autosized having 100% width of the first row image.

Second column is of fixed `1em` width:

`<td rowspan="2" style="width: 0em; padding-left: 1em;"></td>`

Third column, in both rows, contains multi-line no-wrap text of unknown size:

`<td style="width: 0em; white-space: nowrap;">...<br>...</td>`

Last column occupies the remaining space on right side of the table:

`<td rowspan="2" style="width: 100%;"></td>`

**How** to code the first column to force both images being autosized as described above?

---

*NBA and NHL logos/images are registered trademarks and properties of their respective owners.*

Comment: You could definitely do something with [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley - I believe you are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you do.

So in the first square you have (let's call it 1,1) a NBA logo.  Inside of 1,1 we can put an image tag that displays that particular image.  From that point we will set the height to be 100% of the parent div it is in.  Then we would set its width to auto.

That would look something like this:

```
.NBAparentDiv {
     width: x; /*Width that matches NBAlogo aspect ratio*/
     height: y; /*Height that matches NBAlogo aspect ratio*/
}

.NBAparentDiv img {
     height: 100%;
     width: auto;
}
```

Then for the second one we could do the inverse:

```
.NHLparentDiv {
     width: x; /*Width that matches !!NBAlogo!! aspect ratio*/
     height: y; /*Height that matches !!NBAlogo!! aspect ratio*/
}

.NHLparentDiv img {
     height: auto;
     width: 100%;
}
```

That should do what you want for the first column.

Comment: It is **NOT** working, see: https://jsfiddle.net/kv9415fg/ The first logo has to **resize** based on the text content, so it should shrink or enlarge depends on how much text is in the 3rd column.

Comment: @Ωmega Consider adding the suffix 'px' to the end of your width's and height's.  Also, consider resizing your td manually.

Comment: @Ωmega no need to be rude.  What you are trying to do is NOT possible without a script of some sort.  Theoretically you could use a CSS variable the gets the width of one box and resizes the others with a calc function.  But resizing based on just the text alone would not work.  You are asking a style sheet to do a scripts job.